# Why do I have to point to a pointer when building a linked list C++

Tags: c++, pointers

When building a linked-list structure. I have learned the right way to do it, but I don't know why a simpler approach doesn't work. I have searched the internet, I bought a book, I played with the code and theorized and I'm finally calling it quits and willing to deal with some negatives on my question if I just missed something. So here it is:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;


struct Node{
    int data;
    Node* next;

    // Constructor
    Node(int data)
    {
       this->data = data;
       next = NULL;
    }
};

// Class to represent Red-Black Tree
class LinkedList{
private:
    Node* root;
public:
    // Constructor
    LinkedList() { root = NULL; }
    //insert new value into list
    void insert(const int n);
    //print all values from root to end;
    void print();
};

// Function to insert a new node with given data
void LinkedList::insert(const int data){
    Node** pp = &root;
    while (*pp)
        pp = &((*pp)->next);
    *pp = new Node(data);
}

void LinkedList::print(){
    Node** pp = &root;
    while (*pp){
        cout << (*pp)->data << " ";
        pp = &((*pp)->next);
    }
    cout << endl;
}



int main(){
    LinkedList ll;
    ll.insert(5);
    ll.insert(2);
    ll.insert(22);
    ll.print();

    return 0;
}
```

Pretty simple stuff, it runs beautifully. However, This is a problem. Because I don't know WHY I can't do this:

```
void LinkedList::insert(const int data){
    Node* pp = root;
    while (pp)
        pp = pp->next;
    pp = new Node(data);
}
```

It should do the same thing the way I see pointers in my head. And when I write down the address/content pairs on paper, it still makes sense.

Thanks,
-Connor.

Comment: what happens if `root` is null?

Comment: You would - if you only do `pp = pp->next;`. On a side note, you should not include `<bits/stdc++.h>`. Instead, include approriate headers as stated in the documentation for functionality used.

Comment: vu1p3n0x - If root is null 'while (pp)' should  catch that.
SergeyA - That returns nothing.

But maybe this is all returning to the issue of when root is null. But I don't understand why that matters. Shouldn't pp also be null and as such the while loop would never be called.

Comment: yeah, but does it actually do anything? it's supposed to be inserting, root is still null

Comment: Well, after creating new node you shoul be attaching it somehow. I do not see any code for this.

Comment: Because `pp` is a local variable and is gone at the end of the function, thereby immediately leaking the `new Node`.

Comment: This is a really bad idea: `#include <bits/stdc++.h> using namespace std;`. The first line says include the entire standard library. The second says put the entire standard library all in the global namespace. Now you have thousands of classes, functions and other fun stuff that could have the same name as your stuff and may not play well together in the global namespace. Mystery bugs galore as the compiler tries to sort this mess out.

Comment: vu1p3n0x and SergeyA! THANK YOU! I think I finally get it. I always assumed that when you set a pointer to *null* it points to an address but that address is empty. However it literally just = 0; it doesn't point to an empty address. UGH, So much headache over this. Thanks for the push in the right direction!

edit - you know what they say when you 'assume' :P

Comment: Hmmm---I'm not sure I understand your epiphany. A null pointer doesn't "point to" an address--it *is* an address, but an "empty" one. This merely means that it's some kind of unique pointer-value indicating "this pointer is invalid." It *may* be `0` (and is required to be automatically created from `Type* ptr = 0`), but the bits are not *required* to be all `0`s in the implementation, and in fact I've heard of rare systems where the bit-value of `null` is *not* all 0's. But none of that seems to be related to your problem.

Comment: If you meant that you thought a "null pointer" was a *valid* pointer that *points* to "empty" memory, well, that doesn't make any sense. What bit-value represents "emptiness" for, say, an integer? Every possible bit-pattern is a valid numeric value.

Comment: Linked List does not represent a red-black tree

Comment: You do not need to use `Node**`  , you can use `Node *`. But your alternative code has a different bug as pointed out by the answer and comments so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void LinkedList::insert(const int data){
    Node* pp = root;
    while (pp)
        pp = pp->next;
    pp = new Node(data);
}
```

This code doesn't actually do anything. It goes to a lot of trouble to set `pp` to a particular value, only to ignore that value and re-assign `pp` some other value. Then it returns, `pp` goes out of scope, and the value it assigned to it is forever lost.

Let's go through it line by line:

```
void LinkedList::insert(const int data){
    Node* pp = root;
```

At the point, `pp` is a local variable that equals the `root`.

```
while (pp)
    pp = pp->next;
```

This changes the value of `pp` until it runs off the end of the list. So we've gone through the whole list doing nothing else, only to finally break out with `pp` set to `NULL`.

```
    pp = new Node(data);
```

No we create a new `Node` and change `pp`'s value to point to that new `Node`. So we went to all the trouble to make `pp` point to the last node only go past it and then change it to point to a new node.

```
}
```

Now we return, `pp` goes out of scope, and we didn't do anything with the new `Node` either.

You can also see that:

```
void LinkedList::insert(const int data){
    Node* pp = root;
    while (pp)
        pp = pp->next;
    pp = new Node(data);
}
```

is equivalent to (assuming it doesn't run forever):

```
void LinkedList::insert(const int data){
    Node* pp = root;
    pp = NULL;
    pp = new Node(data);
}
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
void LinkedList::insert(const int data){
    Node* pp = NULL;
    pp = new Node(data);
}
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
void LinkedList::insert(const int data){
    Node* pp = new Node(data);
}
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
void LinkedList::insert(const int data){
    new Node(data);
}
```

This clearly creates a new `Node` and promptly leaks it.

Comment: And you can't make the last line `pp->next = new Node(data);` because at this point pp is NULL and has no next pointer so you need to stop before you get to the end so you can assign the last next pointer to the new node.

Comment: There won't be a crash if root is null - the while loop simply won't be entered... The whole essence is that the new node simply is assigned to a local variable only. Apart from that, good answer, +1.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like this way of doing it either:

```
void LinkedList::insert(const int data){
    Node** pp = &root;
    while (*pp)
        pp = &((*pp)->next);
    *pp = new Node(data);
}
```

What I would use is:

```
// returns the last node or NULL on failure
bool LinkedList::insert(const int data){
    Node* pp = root;

    if (!pp){ // if it is an empty list
        root = new Node(data); // assign it to something
        return root; // convert to bool and return - false if new failed
    }

    while (pp->next) // check if we have a next node
        pp = pp->next; // we do have a next node so go there

    // at this point pp->next will be NULL

    pp->next = new Node(data); // assign it to something
    return pp->next; // convert to bool and return - false if new failed
}
```

Comment: How would you want to insert an element into an empty list then?

Comment: To be honest this insert is highly inefficient just to insert to the end of a linked list (or tail). Just store a tail pointer and optimize the insert to make tail's next into this new node, thereby getting rid of the current problems.

Comment: @SenselessCoder Good point - would apply to the whole question, though, not only to this answer...

Comment: @Aconcagua that didn't occur to me - not sure why.  Hopefully this is better.

Comment: @SenselessCoder I probably wouldn't use a singly linked list anyway - depending on what the requirements are there are almost always better data structures.  I was just trying to answer his specific question.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah One problem remains: By returning Node*, you are revealing the internals of the class 'List'. The node class would have to be modified such that instances cannot be changed from outside class 'List' (private members, friend declaration). Preferrably, it should be made an inner class of List.

Comment: @Aconcagua  That's true - it should be an implementation detail of the class.  Leaving the return type as void like the original did is a really bad idea so a bool is probably a better choice.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah "false if new failed" - actually, in this case an exception (::std::bad_alloc) is thrown, so the bool is not of value in this case... Returning Node* is not that a bad idea (think of it as iterator!) - then, however, its internals have to be protected against unwanted access (which is what I wanted to point at...). If I had to write the code, I would only declare the class as inner one in the header and implement it in the cpp file, so its internals are not even visible for whoever is having an eye on the header...

Answer (score 1):

Think that a pointer is simply a variable type that stores a memory address. For example, an int* is simply a variable ("a box") that stores the address of another int variable.

When you do in your "insert" function:

```
Node* pp;
```

pp is a **local** variable of your function that stores an address to a Node object. When you returns from the function, the local variable is destroyed.

When you do:

```
Node ** pp;
```

you define a local variable that stores an address too, but not to a Node object but to a pointer to a Node object, that is, another "intermediate box" that stores the address to the Node object.

And finally, when you do:

```
pp = &((*pp)->next);
```

your local variable, that it will be destroyed when your function returns, stores to the address of the "next" member. Not like when you do:

```
pp = pp->next
```

that you assign to "pp" **the same** address that is stored in "next" (if next is 0x1234, that is a simple value that represents the address to an object, pp will get the same value 0x1234), that will be NULL in the last object of your list.

With the sentence:

```
*pp = new Node(data);
```

The content of "pp" is the address of another pointer to a Node object (not directly the object), in this case, this is the address of the "next" pointer (not the value of the "next" pointer), and when you assign "new Node(data)" to the content of pp, you are assigning the object address to the "next" pointer, which is a member of an object of your list, not a local variable, and what you get is to link your new Node to your list.

To better understand pointers, you can draw in a paper the structure of your variables, painting the pointer as a box that stores an address and have its own address as the variable that is.